# Why Django model signals are not working?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to create activity streams of users from their status.

models:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PRIVACY, default='F')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

However, although I create a new status, it does not create a new activity from the `post_save` signal.

signals:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from status.models import Status
from models import Activity

def create_activity_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)

        if ctype.name == 'Status':
            action = ' shared '

            activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
                actor = instance.user,
                action = action,
                content_type = ctype,
                object_id = instance.id,
                pub_date = instance.pubdate
            )

post_save.connect(create_activity_item, sender=Status)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me solve this problem. I will be very much grateful. Thank you.

**Update:**

However doing like this creates the activity:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Status)
def create(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created',True):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
        activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
            actor = instance.user,
            action = ' shared ',
            content_type = ctype,
            object_id = instance.id,
            pub_date = instance.pub_date
        )
```

Why doesn't the above works then?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Seems like your `post_save.connect` is not executed.  You should import `signals` somewhere.  For django 1.7 it is recommended to do this in the app's config ready() function.  Read the ["Where should this code live?"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) side note in the docs.

For example if your app is called `activity`:

**activity/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'activity.apps.ActivityAppConfig'
```

**activity/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ActivityAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'activity'

    def ready(self):
        import activity.signals
```

And don't forget to add [dispatch_uid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) to your `connect()` call:

```
post_save.connect(create_activity_item, sender=Status,
                  dispatch_uid="create_activity_item")
```

**UPDATE**: `name` attribute of `ContentType` is always in lower case.  So you should change the `if` statement to:

```
if ctype.name == 'status':
```

Comment: hello. I did as you  did in the answer. But it is still not creating any activity. In the `__init__.py` i added `default_app_config = 'activities.apps.ActivityAppConfig'` as activities is the name of the app. And then added a new apps.py file in the app while changing the name field of `ActivityAppConfig` to 'activities'. And then add `dispatch_uid`.

Comment: Yes! Now its working. One more thing. Do I always have to import signals by creating apps.py?  Why doesn't it work without it?

Comment: No, `apps.py` is recommended in official docs but not required.  For example you can `import signals` in `app/__init__.py`.  BTW I prefer define/connect signals right in the `models.py` :-)

Comment: Ok, will remember that! Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer should be on the django documentation.

Comment: the django docs have this, but they make it seem so optional, little do you know nothing works unless all the moons are alighned

Comment: I fixed my issue because I was not registering the config correctly inside the INSTALLED_APPS. I defined 'users.apps.UsersConfig' instead of just 'users' then worked for me.

Comment: Just to remark: your IDE (PyCharm), might say that `import activity.signals` is not used, but don't be fooled, cause Django really uses it for making the signals work for your model. This answer saved me a couple of hours of stress. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Answer (score 22):

If you write everything in `signals.py` correctly but not working, then check these steps... (suppose in an app named AppName)

1. in `__init__.py`, put the line

   ```
   default_app_config = 'AppName.apps.AppnameConfig'
   ```
2. in `apps.py` file, put the block

   ```
   from django.apps import AppConfig


   class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'AppName'

       def ready(self):
           import AppName.signals
   ```

Comment: this worked and I didn't have to add the lines in __init__.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works (without the `init.py`). But I am wondering why we need to do that, and why it doesn't work out of the box with Django ... :/

Answer (score 17):

let's say your apps name is `blog`, in the settings.py file of your project ensure to register the `blog` app in the INSTALLED_APP variable of your main project's settings.py file as `blog.apps.BlogConfig` and not just `blog`. That worked for me.

Comment: Anyone knows why this works?

Comment: you also need to add in `apps.py` >> `def ready(self):  import activity.signals`

Answer (score 8):

The simple, scalable, repeatable, reusable answer is...

If you plan to use signals (ex: `signals.py`) within an app (ex: `posts`), simply **get in the habit of** adding this *method* to your `apps.py` `AppConfig` *class* **everytime**.

```
def ready(self):
    from . import signals
```

You don't need to touch `__init__.py` like others have said. Your signals will then work.

Comment: this is enough for Django 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Without touching **apps.py** this worked for me.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    """ MyModel fields go """
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)


def post_save_actions(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        pass
        # post save actions if new instance is created,
        # do something with `instance` or another models
        # be careful about circular imports. \m/
```

and the signals hook,

```
post_save.connect(post_save_user_actions, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: 1 up for # be careful about circular imports. \m/

Answer (score 0):

You should add

> default_app_config = 'activity.apps.ActivityAppConfig'

in `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 0):

First try with these configurations

1. in `__init__.py` file

   ```
   default_app_config = 'AppName.apps.AppNameConfig'
   ```
2. in `apps.py` file

   ```
   from django.apps import AppConfig


   class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'AppName'

       def ready(self):
           from . import signals
           # import AppName.signals
   ```

But if your application still not working, then don't write app configurations in `__init__.py` file, include your app configrations in `settings.py` file

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'AppName.apps.AppNameConfig',
    ]
```