# handle `post_save` signal in celery

Tags: django, celery, django-signals

I have a rather long running task that needs to be executed after inserting or updating an specific model.

I decided to use `post_save` signal instead of overriding `save` method to reduce coupling. Since Django signals are not asynchronous I had to do the long running job as a Celery task (which we already have in our stack).

A simplified version of my signal handling function is as follows:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    handle_save_task.apply_async(args=(instance.pk,))
```

Also, because the job is done asynchronously I passed the primary key of the object instead of the instance itself.

```
@app.task(queue='elastic')
def handle_save_task(instance_pk):
    try:
        instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # Abort
        logger.warning("Saved object was deleted before this task get a chance to be executed [id = %d]" % instance_pk)
    else:
        # Do my things with instance
```

The actual problem is that when the celery task is executed it can't access the newly saved instance. Just like if it was executed prior to saving! (wasn't the signal called **post_**save? What an irony)

By "executed before saving" I mean if it is a new instance that's being inserted to DB, in the celery task I get an `DoesNotExist` exception and in cases where instance was already in DB and the save method was called to update some of its properties I get the old instance with old property values in the celery task.

A workaround is to run celery tasks with a few seconds of delay, but obviously it is not a good solution and also can not guarantee the proper execution behavior under heavy loads or long network delays.

Am I doing it completely wrong or with some slight modifications I can make it work?

Comment: Do you by any chance use a transaction.atomic() somewhere in your call stack which doesn't get committed before your task is triggered?

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns Honestly that was a really good guess but I don't think so. I tried it from shell and from django admin, I'm not sure whether django admin creates a transaction to save instances but the problem occured in both cases.

Comment: I haven't used the Django admin much but I do think it (used to) create a transaction for updates and it does seem to fit with the reported behaviour (see also the celery docs http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#database-transactions). There seems to be a project on github intended to solve problems with transactions and celery (https://github.com/fellowshipofone/django-celery-transactions) although it does seem to be unmaintained. Maybe it's worth it to take a look.

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns I double checked it. The problem only occures when updating from django admin not in shell, so your transaction guess seems very plausible...

Comment: That's good to hear, at least we localized the cause. Shall I post it as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is probably caused by your update being performed inside a transaction. The transaction is committed after the Celery Task has already started which causes the Celery Task to see your old value when running.

You can try the following change:

```
from django.db import transaction

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: handle_save_task.apply_async(args=(instance.pk,)))
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped

Comment: can we use `transaction.on_commit` for django version 1.8?

Comment: I'm not sure whether on_commit is available in 1.8

Comment: I created signals.py and put this code inside ( with my own task function ) and nothing happened, tried to add logs, the logs not appear on console. where should I put this code? models class?

Comment: @taipei the problem you're facing seems a bit of a different one. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135029/django-signals-not-working to see if that helps

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns thank you, I was missing some steps.

Comment: Can someone please explain, why do we need the lambda function inside `on_commit` ?

Comment: @Abhimanyu, that is because you don't want to pass a result of `apply_async` method execution to the on_commit, but you want to tell that you need to execute that method with these args whenever commit will be done