# How to extract function name that has been passed as an argument to Python's lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

Lets say I have a function `foo`:

```
def foo():
    print('something')
```

and I am passing this above function to lambda function along with assigning it to a variable.

```
bar = lambda: foo
```

So, if I have the `bar` object how can I extract that name of the function that was passed to it i.e`foo`?

I tried to list all the methods of that `bar` object using `dir(bar)`, couldn't find much to extract the desired result.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with higher-order functions or lambdas, this is just the way to get the name of something in Python.

Comment: You're not passing `foo` into a lambda function here. You're writing a lambda function that returns it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: why are you using a lambda that has no params and returns `foo`. Just use `foo`?

Comment: @Pynchia it just and sample example that I showed the real use case is a bit complex and of course I am passing argument.

Comment: @Holloway related to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279060/5964750

Comment: I think you could do with updating the question to better match your use case. If you're actually using `bar = lambda x: foo(x)` there is no way to extract the name `foo` from bar (except maybe via some dis/ast hack).

Comment: @Holloway I have a combination of functions passed with the post_save of different model instance. Now I want to write test cases to check conditions like `foo1` will be passed inside post_save event of model `M1` post save, `foo2` will be passed for post save of model `M2` and so on.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, I agree the example is a bit odd but `bar = lambda: foo` and `bar = foo` are not the same.

Comment: @Holloway I agree they are slightly different. The lambda returns `foo` as a callable which needs to be called again. There is almost never a need for this unless you are monkey typing in default variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly do that, but you can call `bar`, which returns `foo`, and check its `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> bar().__name__
'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `bar = lambda: foo` instead of just `bar = foo`?
The `lambda` returns a the `foo` object meaning you have to do something like:

```
bar = lambda: foo
# now to call foo:
bar()()
```

Functions are first class objects in python so you don't need a lambda for something this simple.

```
bar = foo
print(bar.__name__) # foo
# now to call foo:
bar()
```

It would be a different story if you wanted to pass default arguments:

```
def foo(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
y = 3
z = 2
bar = lambda x, y=y, z=z: foo(x, y, z)
# now to call foo:
bar(1) # 1 3 2
# but printing the name is this case is more tricky since the 
# lambda isn't return the function object but the return value
# of that function.
# Thus you would need to use inspect like the answer below.
```

Comment: `bar(1).__name__` wouldn't work with that example because it'd be reading the `__name__` attribute on whatever `foo` returns not `foo` itself (in this case `None`).

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to call the function to get his name (as suggested in other answers), you can `inspect` your function to get the code, and from there work your way out to get the passed function's name:

```
def foo():
    print('something')

bar = lambda: foo

print(inspect.getsource(bar))
```

Output:

> bar = lambda: foo

And finding the provided function shouldn't be complicated, i.e.:

```
func_code = inspect.getsource(bar)
passed_function = func_code.split(' ')[-1]

print(passed_function)
```

Output:

> foo

Even if you have multiple arguments, you can extract the provided function's name:

```
import inspect


def foo(x, y, z):
    print('something')

bar = lambda x, y, z: foo(x, y, z)

func_code = inspect.getsource(bar)
print(func_code)
passed_function = func_code.split('(')[0].split(' ')[-1]

print(passed_function)
```

Output:

> foo

Comment: This is incredibly fragile, eg I could write a `bar = lambda:foo` or `bar = lambda x,y,z : foo(x, y, z)` and it'd fail, even if the variable is exactly the same.

Comment: I do get your point, but that's a different problem. It looks fragile because that's an example, but parsing and extracting function's name is how [static analysis tools](http://opensourceforu.com/2011/09/joy-of-programming-technology-behind-static-analysis-tools/) works.

Comment: If you were running the source through `ast.parse` or similar, then yes, it would be possible but I doubt any static analysis tools rely on splitting on whitespace.

Comment: @Holloway splitting on whitespaces was an example; [examples](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/example#English) is a _non-exhaustive_ conceptualization representative of a bigger group (in this case, parsing). Static analysis tools do not rely on that, but they do [parse the code](http://opensourceforu.com/2011/09/joy-of-programming-technology-behind-static-analysis-tools/)! so: understood the critique, not the case.