# django celery tasks are executed before establishing a websocket connection

Tags: django, websocket, celery, django-celery, django-channels

The user uploads the file to the form, after which the form with the file is sent to the server, and upon successful validation, I perform the following actions:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    storage = FileSystemStorage()
    file_path = storage.save(form.cleaned_data['file'].name, form.cleaned_data['file'])
    task = tasks.extract_text_from_pdf.delay(services.full_path(file_path))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pdf:download_result', kwargs={'task_id': task.id}))
```

I temporarily save the file to the local file system and pass the file path to the celery task.

After submitting the task to celeri, I redirect the user to another page where I establish a websocket connection to the server to be notified of the file processing result.

In celery tasks, I open a file and perform the necessary actions with it, after which I send a message to the consumer.

```
@shared_task
def send_notification(message, task_id):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

    room_group_name = f'download_result_{task_id}'

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'notification_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )


@shared_task
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file_path):
    with open(pdf_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(BytesIO(file.read()))

    text = ""
    for page in reader.pages:
        text += page.extract_text() + "\n"

    text = text.replace('\n', '\r\n')

    send_notification.delay(text, current_task.request.id)
```

But I encountered a problem - celery tasks are executed faster than the websocket connection is established and as a result the message does not reach the client side.

```
src.pdf_processing.tasks.extract_text_from_pdf[8f535575-803d-4679-8007-7a4404a372c1] 
succeeded in 0.148360932000287s: None
src.pdf_processing.tasks.send_notification[8cbf5934-47fc-4bdb-98d8-fbdec9720ec3] 
received
src.pdf_processing.tasks.send_notification[8cbf5934-47fc-4bdb-98d8-fbdec9720ec3] 
succeeded in 0.006449124999562628s: None
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/download_result/8f535575-803d-4679-8007-7a4404a372c1/ 
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/download_result/8f535575-803d-4679-8007-7a4404a372c1/
```

How can this problem be solved? Maybe some other approach to establish a websocket connection should be used? Thank you!

Comment: You may store the result in the database and summon that when web socket connects

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276828/handle-post-save-signal-in-celery

Comment: check this too, On commit hook will work once the object is saved https://medium.com/hypertrack/dealing-with-database-transactions-in-django-celery-eac351d52f5f