# Testing Anymail webhook locally, unable to receive signal

Tags: django, webhooks, mailgun, django-anymail

I am trying to test my setup for Anymail (using Mailgun) webhooks. Currently  using https://ngrok.com/ which redirects an HTTPS address to a local address to properly handle localhost:80 addresses.

Mailgun allows to send test requests to a webhook, which points to the temporary ngrok provided addres, something like:

```
https://random:random@somthing.ngrok.io/webhooks/anymail/mailgun/tracking/
```

Following [anymail-webhooks](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/#configuring-tracking-and-inbound-webhooks) the app is currently able to actually receive the webhook call as shown in the logs:

```
web          | "POST /webhooks/anymail/mailgun/tracking/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

The response code 200 indicates the backend received the webhook correctly and sent an acknowdledge.

The url is set here:

```
path('webhooks/anymail/', include('anymail.urls')),
```

and the signal receiver is as simple as:

```
from anymail.signals import tracking
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(tracking)
def handle_signal(sender, event, esp_name, **kwargs):
    print('[ --- ] {}'.format(event))
```

I expect to see something in my shell for every POST to `/webhooks/anymail/mailgun/tracking/` but apparently the receiver is never receiving the signal and thus not printing anything.

I went over this a couple of times and I can't figure what am I missing.

Comment: Where in your project have you put the code that listens for the `tracking` signal?

Comment: And following on @solarissmoke's question, is the file with your `handle_signal` receiver actually imported by some other file in your project? Try logging something like `print('signal handler loaded')` at the root of your signal handler file to make sure it's getting loaded. If not, see (e.g.) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135149/647002).